# why is getdescriptorinfo returning a "function needed" error with a sortedmulti descriptor?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, output-script-descriptors

When trying:

```
bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wsh(sortedmulti(2,tpubDFck48zH8ZzteKKZCR9WMVBJwHZayhQmtCDyDRzHsU7VMTwEXohD23h1CBiizKtFtWck2fVegNDRM193nGx3VLs1RTSGNc1iePKpc1JvsS6/*,tpubDEfXroYtWB6rQ1vNuCUAErUJtxSQ6bjxtz63rWWRaByADcudNFtV6HZz5PM7yeXQLG4GWmrdcRkMEGgdXWWu5TyuRpMXURCiwJoGQYH743f/*,tpubDFSz52YB4yCdbgKeLB5BcJfW1f1AzmLcdzB3nGz6Yft2MVHy2rj4uXBFT8d3maYS4rCxjJdBfExJAM9JCjWmYzkJyaLP4Rk8nALDUSfWbT8/*))"
```

I get:

```
error code: -5
error message:
A function is needed within P2WSH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This call works fine for me. What version of the code are you using? `sortedmulti` is not in 0.19, only in master (and will be in 0.20).

Comment: ahh ok, will update